# Recasting *void function arguments

Tags: void-pointers

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434884/nlopt-with-armadillo-data) earlier that I think I can answer if someone can help me with the following:

I have a function

```
double func(void* data)
```

I want to pass in an object or struct. (In my case an armadillo matrix or even just and std::vector).

*How do I pass a pointer to an object as an argument to func() and then, once inside func(), how do I recast the void pointer into its original type?*

**Edit**: Here's what ended up working, where mat is the Armadillo matrix class:

```
mat A(2,2);
A << 1 << 2 << endr << 3 << 4; // A=[1,2; 3,4]
func(&A);
```

and in func:

```
double func(void* data) {
   mat* pB = (mat*)(data);
   mat B = pB[0];
}
```

The matrix B and A now contain the same data.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you need something like this.

```
double func(void* data_v) {
  struct my_type * data = data_v;
}

func((void*)my_data);
```

Comment: Thank you. This pointed me in the right direction. See my edit above for what ended up working.

Comment: Is a second pointer always needed? Could not it be possible to recycle the same `*data_v`?