# Bus Error with strncpy in C

Tags: c, substring, c-strings, strncpy, bus-error

I am working on the same project as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995287/access-element-of-struct-passed-into-a-void-pointer), however with a slightly different typedef:

```
typedef struct {
    char* word;
    int index;
} data_t;

typedef struct node node_t;

typedef node {
    void *data;
    node_t *left;
    node_t *right;
}
```

I am trying to split a string into individual words, sticking it into the data_t struct and then inserting it into a binary search tree.  The idea is that, while looping across an input string, when it is found that the character is one which marks the end of a word, the number of characters between the start and end of the word is copied into a string, which I have attempted to do using:

```
strncpy(newstring, (in+wordstart), (i-wordstart));
```

where:

```
char* newstring, in;
int i, wordstart;
```

However, gcc gives a bus error when that particular line is called.  How this bus error can be fixed and the current solution kept, or would it be wiser to look for a different solution?

The only idea I have been able to think of so far is to, one character at a time, put the characters into the string until the end of the word has been reached.

Comment: You'll need to post more of the code.

Comment: How are you allocating memory for all those strings?

Comment: `char* newstring, in` are just pointers to some random memory. You do need to make them point to some valid memory, memory belonging to the process.

Comment: yeah memory wasn't being allocated at all.  sticking in `newstring = malloc(strlen(in)-wordstart);` seems to make it work.

Comment: Consider allocating `+1` character to store the 0-terminator. @disgruntledperson

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't declare two pointers, this is just one pointer and a char

```
char* newstring, in;
```

It should be declared like this:

```
char *newstring, *in;
```

Also, as someone else noted, it doesn't seem that you're allocating any memory for those pointers.

Comment: Good catch! And another nice example why to always declare a variable on it's own line! ;-)

Comment: haha very good point there and thanks for pointing it out! Honestly I put that there to indicate how the strncpy line was type defined.  in is passed in to the function via `char *in`, though `newstring` was declared as above.  Apologies for that though I will keep your point in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
typedef node {
    void *data;
    node_t *left;
    node_t *right;
}
```

doesn't make any sense at all. There's no `struct` keyword before the `node`, and no name for the type alias you're trying to introduce after the `}`, and no terminating semi colon. This shouldn't compile.